# Evaluate the integral in terms of inverse hyperbolic functions and natural logarithms

Tags: calculus, integration, hyperbolic-functions

Evaluate the integral in terms of a) inverse hyperbolic functions, and b) natural logarithms.

$$\int_0^{2\sqrt3} \frac{dx}{\sqrt{4+x^2}}$$

I solved *a)* but I can't figure out how to do *b)*. I don't even know where to start. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: $$\frac{dx}{\sqrt{x^2+a^2}}=\log|x+\sqrt{x^2+a^2}|$$

Comment: Let $x=2\tan(\alpha)$. we have $4+x^2=4+4\tan^2(\alpha)=\dfrac{4}{\cos^2(\alpha)}$ and $\text{d}x=\dfrac{2}{\cos^2(\alpha)}$. Could you manage to continue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hints:**

The basic formulae to know are

- $\DeclareMathOperator\ash{argsinh}\displaystyle\int\frac{\mathrm d\mkern1.5mu x}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}=\ash x,\;$ from which we deduce by substitution $$\int\frac{\mathrm d\mkern1.5mu x}{\sqrt{x^2+a^2}}=\frac1a\ash\Bigl(\frac xa\Bigr).$$
- $\ash x=\ln\bigl(x+\sqrt{x^2+1}\bigr)$.

For the last formula,  $y=\ash x$   means $\sinh y =\dfrac{\mathrm e^{2y}-1}
{2\mathrm e^y}=x$. So $u=\mathrm e^y$ is the positive root of the quadratic equation
$$u^2-2xu-1=0, \enspace\text{i.e.}\quad u=x+\sqrt{x^2+1},$$
whence the formula.

The definite integral is thus
$$\frac12\ash\Bigl(\frac x2\Bigr)\Bigg\lvert_0^{2\sqrt3}=\frac12\,\ash\bigl(\sqrt3\bigr)=\frac12\ln(\sqrt3+2).$$

Comment: This may be too late but I have just come across this. The integral of $\int{\frac{\text{d}u}{\sqrt{{{u}^{2}}+{{a}^{2}}}}}={{\sinh }^{-1}}\left( \frac{u}{a} \right)+C$. There is no $\frac{1}{a}$ in this integral.